# Django if now = post date in template

Tags: django

I'm a bit lost, In my MySQL DB DateField is saved like that 2020-10-29

In my template I try to see if DateField == Now. In my models it's DateField not a DateTimeField

So I've try to do this:

```
{% now "Y-F-j" as current_date %}
{% if post.start_date == current_date  %} Today{% else %} Ended{% endif %}
```

But even if it should match I got ended everywhere... Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my MySQL DB DateField is saved like that 2020-10-29.

**No**, that is just the *formatting* of how it presents it to the outside world. For a `DateField`, you should assume it save a `date` object `datetime` object. Not a string.

I would advice to pass the current day to the context:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

def my_view(request):
    # …
    context = {
        # …,
        'today' : now().date()
    }
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

and then compare this with the `start_date` of the `post` object:

```
{% if post.start_date == today %} Today{% else %} Ended{% endif %}
```

Note that Django has a [**`|timesince`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) to present a `date`(`time`) object in a more pleasant way.